# arabi package and page numbering

Tags: pdftex, page-numbering, arabic

I'm actually using arabi package, and the issue is that i can't change the style of page numbers, for instance, alph or roman...

I'm sure it is not a big issue if i use XeLaTex, but i need the solution for pdfLaTex.

Here an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}%


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %

\usepackage[english,arabic]{babel} %


\begin{document}%

\frontmatter

\pagenumbering{alph}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{مرحبا بكم}

اهلا و سهلا و مرحبا


\end{document} %
```

So, how can i fix this?

Comment: You might be able to use `\babelprovide[import, alph = abjad, main]{arabic}` to define `\pagenumbering{alph}` the way you want.

Comment: Fsiling that, I give [an example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/544982/61644) of how to use a counter in another language with `fancyhdr`; you could replace `\hindicounter{page}` with `\arabiccounter{page}` or even `\localecounter{abjad}{page}`.