# Most suitable package for using Hindi / Sanskrit?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, hindi

I am using Overleaf for documentation, in that I want to use some quotes of old Sanskrit and give Hindi numbering to pages.

So any suitable package for doing SO.

Answer (score 3):

I unfortunately don’t speak Hindi and cannot tell you what is the best, or what most authors from India use.

What I would normally recommend is to compile in xelatex rather than pdftex.  Since you are using Overleaf, you can change the TeX engine from the project menu.  (The latest version of lualatex adds suppprt for South Asian scripts, but Overleaf has yet to upgrade.)  Then you can load `babel`, type in Devanagari normally, and save in UTF-8.

[The babel package uses the `\localenumeral` and `\localecounter` commands to display numbers in other scripts.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf#subsection.1.17)  It supports `alphabetic` numbering for Hindi.  You might also be able to change the meaning of `\pagenumbering{alph}`.

If you are genuinely forced to use pdftex, and you want to include a paragraph-long quotation in Sanskrit, a workaround would be to compile that quotation as a `standalone` PDF in xetex and include it in the document you compile with pdftex, as if it were a figure.  Hindi page numbering would be more complex.

Otherwise, there is an older package, `devanagari`, that you might get to work.

There is a somewhat simpler approach than I had originally used, which is use the `maparabic` language option to change the behavior of `arabic` numeric counters, and `layout=sectioning` package option to make section numbers and the table of contents use the numerals of the current language.  It is also possible to override `alph` counters for Hindi.

```
\tracinglostchars=2 % Show a warning for missing characters
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm]{geometry} % Solely to crop a MWE on TeX.SX
\usepackage[bidi=default,layout=sectioning]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\babelprovide[import,main,maparabic]{hindi}
\babelprovide[import]{sanskrit-devanagari}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[hindi]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\babelfont[hindi]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\babelfont[sanskrit-devanagari]{rm}
          {Noto Serif Devanagari}
\babelfont[sanskrit-devanagari]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{Noto Sans Devanagari}

\newcommand\texthindi[1]{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{#1}}
\newenvironment{hindi}%
{\begin{otherlanguage}{hindi}}%
{\end{otherlanguage}}
\newcommand\textsanskrit[1]{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit-devanagari}{#1}}
\newenvironment{sanskrit}%
{\begin{otherlanguage}{sanskrit-devanagari}}%
{\end{otherlanguage}}
\newcommand\textenglish[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}
\newenvironment{english}%
{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}%
{\end{otherlanguage}}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
Text in English and \texthindi{हिन्दी}.  Unless I’ve fallen for a very elaborate
practical joke, this should be an excerpt from the UN Declaration of Human
Rights:

\begin{sanskrit}
सर्वे मानवाः स्वतन्त्राः समुत्पन्नाः वर्तन्ते अपि च, गौरवदृशा अधिकारदृशा च समानाः एव वर्तन्ते। एते सर्वे चेतना-तर्क-शक्तिभ्यां सुसम्पन्नाः सन्ति। अपि च, सर्वेऽपि बन्धुत्व-भावनया परस्परं व्यवहरन्तु।
\end{sanskrit}
\end{document}
```

#### Original Anawer

Here is a simple template that compiles in xelatex.  I apologize for any errors:

```
\tracinglostchars=2 % Show a warning for missing characters
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm]{geometry} % Solely to crop a MWE on TeX.SX
\usepackage[english, bidi=default]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\babelprovide[import]{hindi}
\babelprovide[import]{sanskrit-devanagari}

\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[hindi]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\babelfont[hindi]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\babelfont[sanskrit-devanagari]{rm}
          {Noto Serif Devanagari}
\babelfont[sanskrit-devanagari]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{Noto Sans Devanagari}

\newcommand\texthindi[1]{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{#1}}
\newenvironment{hindi}%
{\begin{otherlanguage}{hindi}}%
{\end{otherlanguage}}
\newcommand\textsanskrit[1]{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit-devanagari}{#1}}
\newenvironment{sanskrit}%
{\begin{otherlanguage}{sanskrit-devanagari}}%
{\end{otherlanguage}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\texthindi{\hindicounter{page}}}
\fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}
Text in English and \texthindi{हिन्दी}.  Unless I’ve fallen for a very elaborate
practical joke, this should be an excerpt from the UN Declaration of Human
Rights:

\begin{sanskrit}
सर्वे मानवाः स्वतन्त्राः समुत्पन्नाः वर्तन्ते अपि च, गौरवदृशा अधिकारदृशा च समानाः एव वर्तन्ते। एते सर्वे चेतना-तर्क-शक्तिभ्यां सुसम्पन्नाः सन्ति। अपि च, सर्वेऽपि बन्धुत्व-भावनया परस्परं व्यवहरन्तु।
\end{sanskrit}
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto font sample]

Comment: having an error still.

Comment: @Kul It worked for me using LuaLaTeX from TeX Live 2020. Older versions of XeLaTeX should also be able to compile it. What error are you getting? What distribution and TeX engine are you using?

Comment: Yep, it worked fine again thanks!!